# pip download --build either deletes or moves packages after download completes

Tags: download, pip, installation, anaconda

I'm having an issue with pip when pip install cannot download packages due to a no space error.  While I investigate that, I'm trying to setup a work around by downloading the packages to a set folder, and then doing an offline installation, using:

```
pip download --no-cache-dir tensorflow -b /home/profile1/tmp/
```

In my research, I found that pip uses the root `/tmp` folder by default, and that it clears it after a successful installation. So, I set it to go to a different `/tmp` folder under the `/profile1` directory. The command seems to work fine, but when I look at the directory it is empty.  I've ruled out that the packages do not download by running it again, this time opening a new terminal.  I navigated to `/profile1/tmp` and used `ls` while tensorflow downloaded.  The package and its dependency packages downloaded - however, they dissappeared once the download was complete (used `ls -ltra` to confirm). I believe they are being moved, because when I used `df -h /home`, there was an increase in the space used.  I need to be able to keep them in the /tmp folder, for installation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I tried using @sinoroc answer, and while it worked for the download, it still crashes with a no space error:

```
pip download --no-cache-dir tensorflow -d /home/profile1/tmp/

#downloads several packages
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/profile1/anaconda3/envs/testinstall/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 186, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/profile1/anaconda3/envs/testinstall/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/download.py", line 135, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/home/profile1/anaconda3/envs/testinstall/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 177, in resolve
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
  File "/home/profile1/anaconda3/envs/testinstall/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 333, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/home/profile1/anaconda3/envs/testinstall/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 282, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(req)
  File "/home/profile1/anaconda3/envs/testinstall/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 482, in prepare_linked_requirement
    hashes=hashes,
  File "/home/profile1/anaconda3/envs/testinstall/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 287, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes,
  File "/home/profile1/anaconda3/envs/testinstall/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 164, in unpack_http_url
    unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type)
  File "/home/profile1/anaconda3/envs/testinstall/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/unpacking.py", line 252, in unpack_file
    flatten=not filename.endswith('.whl')
  File "/home/profile1/anaconda3/envs/testinstall/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/unpacking.py", line 139, in unzip_file
    shutil.copyfileobj(fp, destfp)
  File "/home/profile1/anaconda3/envs/testinstall/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfileobj
    fdst.write(buf)
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

On using `df -h /home', I see that I have 20 GB left in the file system. Is there anything else I can do as far as remediation goes?

EDIT 2:
I was able to confirm that this is only with pip; I was able to use `conda install` to get tensorflow, but not pip.

Comment: Do not edit your question to ask a different one, only loosely related to the original issue.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem, thanks for understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for the `--dest <dir>` option.

```
$ pip download --help
[...]
-d, --dest <dir>            Download packages into <dir>.
```

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_download/#cmdoption-d

Comment: While this worked to get the .whl files downloaded, now pip crashes with a no space error.  I've already checked an found that I have 20 GB left in the home file system, so I'm not sure why its complaining about this.

Comment: OK, then let's accept this answer and start fresh with a new question, for this second different issue to keep things clean and easy to browse for the next people that encounter the same original issue.